# Faster lapply web-scraping in R

Tags: r, web-scraping, lapply

Any clue how I might speed up the following web scraping function.  I have a vector of ~60k unique URLs that I am currently running through the script and it takes about 7 hours currently.

```
url_vector_full=df1[["pagePath"]]
url_vector=unique(url_vector_full)

SafeGet = function (x)  {
    tryCatch({
    #   short_url_vector
    html=GET(x)
    parsed=htmlParse(html)
    root=xmlRoot(parsed)
    title = xpathSApply(root, "//h1[@class='page-h1'][1]", xmlValue)
    return(title)},
    error=function(e){cat("ERROR :", conditionMessage(e))}, '0')}

website_responses <- pbmclapply(url_vector, SafeGet, mc.preschedule=T)
title=trimws(website_responses)
```

Any pointers that would increase performance here would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may be parallelizing one request on many cores but it's far more useful to run many jobs on one core.

```
  library(curl)
  # Init list of urls to be read
  url_vector_full=df1[["pagePath"]]
  url_vector=unique(url_vector_full)
  parsed_url <- list()

  cb <- function(req){
    parsed_url <<- append(parsed_url, list(rawToChar(req$content)))
  }

  # Specify chunk size to prevent exceeding API rate limit
  chunk_size <- 50

  for (i in 1:ceiling(length(url_vector) / chunk_size)) {

    pool <- new_pool()

    # vector of uris to loop through
    uris <- url_vector[(i + (i - 1) * (chunk_size - 1)):(i * chunk_size)]

    # all scheduled requests are performed concurrently
    sapply(uris, curl_fetch_multi, done=cb, pool=pool)

    # Perform requests
    out <- multi_run(pool = pool)

    # Print out number of successes each round
    cat(sum(out$success))

    # Delay calls to prevent exceeding speed limit
    Sys.sleep(2)
  }
```

1. Play around to make this work as I don't know your
   dataset, but once you do, it will work much faster.
2. Be careful not to get blocked for
   making requests too fast, hence the feature to chunk and
   Sys.sleep your calls.
3. Also, once you get your urls, you can extract them as you do in your code.

Comment: If I'm reading your code correctly, one of the main things you think I should do is split the HTML-parsing and extraction into two separate steps, correct?

Comment: My initial reaction to seeing this script in action is that it appears slower than what I have...

Another apparent problem I have with this method is that I need the output to retain the original order so I can combine the output back into the source dataframe.  I noticed that the chunks are sometimes less than 50, meaning the output is smaller than the inputs.  My method deals with this by adding a zero to the output whenever a URL fails.

Comment: 1. Yes, though I'm sure there's a way to do it in one step. 2. I'd play with the sleep length and chunk sizes. I kept these parameters from code that I aimed to run overnight, and not under tight constraints. 3. I'm not sure how to address the skipped fails, though there might be a way to add options into the call